# Python: running a script that turns into a background process dies immediatly

Tags: python, process, background

I'm working on a piece of code in python where I'm using `parallel-ssh` to run a script on a Raspberry Pi. The script runs for about a 1 and then disappears even though there is `nohup` in the script.

Code to run the script from server:

```
return subprocess.call(["parallel-ssh", "-h", hosts_path, "-o", "pssh-out", "-e", "pssh-err", "-i" if inline else "", cmd])
```

and on the Raspberry Pi the script looks like this:

```
log_path=$1

tty_path=`ls /dev/serial/by-id/usb-MBED_MBED_CMSIS-DAP_*`
nohup /home/pi/scripts/ble/contiki-serialdump -b9600 $tty_path | /home/pi/scrip$


sleep 1
ps | grep "$! "

#exit $?
```

Any ideas why it doesn’t keep running in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Your script isn't waiting before it exits.  You'll need a shell with job control (such as Bash), and use the `wait` builtin command.  Read the `bash` man page to understand `wait`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was apparently that the usb hub needed to be turned off and on in order for the serial dump to start properly